# Visual Studio 2010 C++ Release Mode Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile my c++ project in visual studio 2010, that has been running fine in debug mode for the past several months. I am finished developing it, so I would like to create an exe to release.

The issue is that I am receiving a bunch of compiler errors when I switch it to release mode that I am not sure how to debug.

Any help would be appreciated:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl initKinect(void)" (?initKinect@@YAHXZ) already defined in gui.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: _main already defined in gui.obj
1>Kinect.lib(Kinect-win32.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in algorithm.obj
1>Kinect.lib(Kinect-win32.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' specification
1>Kinect.lib(Kinect-Driver.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in algorithm.obj
1>Kinect.lib(Kinect-FrameInput.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in algorithm.obj
1>libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in algorithm.obj
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __heap_alloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(malloc.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __recalloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(recalloc.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __msize already defined in LIBCMT.lib(msize.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbghook.obj) : error LNK2005: __crt_debugger_hook already defined in LIBCMT.lib(dbghook.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(isctype.obj) : error LNK2005: __isctype_l already defined in LIBCMT.lib(isctype.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(isctype.obj) : error LNK2005: __isctype already defined in LIBCMT.lib(isctype.obj)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Kinect\repository\KinectTracker\Release\KinectTracker.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like you are linking two sets of libraries (besides possible other problems). Libcmtd is multithreaded-debug version of libc, and libcmt is release version of same thing.